# How to fix "Return type must be {SomeClassName}" error?

Tags: java, methods

I have created a new class called `SomeCode`. I have another class called `SomeAccount`.
I need to create a method inside of `SomeCode` that returns a `SomeAccount` object.

Here is what I have tried:

```
public SomeCode toBarcode () {
    String BarCodeSource = toString();
    int barCodeNumber = Integer.parseInt(BarCodeSource);
    return barCodeNumber;      
}
```

The error I am getting is "Return type must be `SomeCode`", which is true, I just don't know how to fix it.

Comment: You sir have left me speechless I'm so confused

Comment: @BahramGhebray - Your question was very confusing, so I revised the wording to clarify things. If it does not accurately reflect what you are asking, please update it.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning an `int` but you declared your function to return a `SomeCode`.

You have to return a `SomeCode` object or change your function return type to an `int`.

Also, not sure what you are doing using the `toString()` method.

Based on your question, if you want to return an `int`, you should change:

```
public SomeCode toBarcode () {
    String BarCodeSource = toString();  
    int barCodeNumber = Integer.parseInt(BarCodeSource);
    return barCodeNumber;      
}
```

To:

```
public int toBarcode () {
    String BarCodeSource = toString();  
    int barCodeNumber = Integer.parseInt(BarCodeSource);
    return barCodeNumber;      
}
```

Or, if you want to return `SomeCode`, you have to specify what you want to do with it.

You need to create it somewhere in your code by saying:

`SomeCode variableName = new SomeCode();`

and then return what you created by saying:

`return variableName;`

A pointless yet correct answer would be to change:

```
public SomeCode toBarcode () {
    String BarCodeSource = toString();  
    int barCodeNumber = Integer.parseInt(BarCodeSource);
    return barCodeNumber;      
}
```

To:

```
public SomeCode toBarcode () {
    SomeCode var = new SomeCode();
    return var;     
}
```

You have to clarify your question further if you want us to help.

Comment: Yes how do I return SomeCode object type?

Comment: well you need to create it somewhere in your code by saying SomeCode variableName = new SomeCode(); and then return what you created by saying return variableName;

Comment: ya, i think that's what i was missing. i need to declare it first. new to this stuff. thanks for helping me out